# Refresh content of DialogFragment without dismissing it

Tags: android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I've an `Activity` A with a method called `methodOne()`.

`methodOne()` contains a code snippet that triggers a `DialogFragment`. I'm using `newInstance` with an argument while initialising that `DialogFragment`.

I also have a corresponding adapter called DummyAdapter to this activity This adapter contains a `ViewPager`. It acts as a list item.
When I swipe the Viewpager, it calls `methodOne()`inside Activity A.

This method triggers a `DialogFragment`. This `DialogFragment` has a `viewpager` inside it.

Now, whenever I swipe the viewpager from the `DummyAdapter` which in turn calls the `methodOne()` I would like to refresh the DialogFragment's content without dismissing the Dialog. Is that possible? If yes then how? Refreshing basically includes passing the new argument to the `DialogFragment` newInstance's constructor and then `notifydatasetchanged` to the `viewpager`.